# RSA encryption private key among a group of people

Tags: django, security, cryptography, rsa

I am currently trying to implement the RSA encryption algorithm with my Django application. So the way I want it to be Is that the users enter some data through like quiz or surveys and then that data is encrypted using a public key of the users. Then I have a group of admins who only can see what the user enters in their own portal (not the Django admin), like maybe a group of admins at a school or something .

How can I implement this ? Because a thing that struck me is that I can't decrypt the data with multiple private keys since 1 user's data can be shown to multiple admins for analysis purposes. So I want that a user's data should be decrypted and shown in the admin portal of multiple admins.

Comment: What is the thing you want to achieve? Who should encrypt what, who should be allowed to decrypt and who not? Or maybe it is not that much about encryption, as of making sure the cipher text originates from a specific user?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You encrypt the symmetric encryption key with the public key of everyone who is authorized to decrypt the data. If there are 5 people who are so authorized then you have the encrypted message concatenated with the symmetric encryption key encrypted with the public keys of 5 different people. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem